# Magento 2 - Cancel order incrementing 2 quantity of product

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, magento-2.2.5, stock-status

In Magento 2.2.5 EE

**Before placing order**:
Product quantity = 1
stock status = 1

**After placing order**:
product quantity = 0
stock status = 0

**After cancel order**:
product quantity = 2
stock status = 1

I have check in my code, there is no `order_cancel_after` or `sales_order_save_after` or `sales_order_state_change_before` observer in any custom module.

Any idea what would be the issue?

Comment: You checked here in this table?: cataloginventory_stock_status

Comment: Yes, it has same result which I have added in question.

Comment: Please check once in Fresh Setup, Cause I have already checked in fresh setup, but yeah I have Added one more step after Cancel order RUN command indexer:reindex. I didn't get mentioned issue.

Comment: Yes, most probably it will work fine on fresh setup. I just want to know from where this is happening? I have canceled order programmatically and also from admin, both are incrementing 2 quantities. I have check some observers, I want to know what else should I check to debug the issue

Comment: Might somewhere it happens due to after save order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had checked these observers in my codebase:

- order_cancel_after
- sales_order_save_after
- sales_order_state_change_before

I haven't found above observers in any of my custom/installed module.

But now I found the issue, there was an observer `sales_order_save_before` in a custom payment method, it was increasing quantity on order cancel. So, when I was canceling the order Magento increasing order quantity (Which is a default functionality) and also this observer (sales_order_save_before) was also increasing quantity.

That's way quantity was increasing twice.